# Kettle over kettle transform file pentaho CDE

Tags: database-connection, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-cde

Facing issue regarding **kettle over kettle transform step** in pentaho CDE, i have created transformation file and it is working perfectly.

Properties of kettle over kettle transform step where i have option of **select transformation file**, so when i am browsing it i am able to see only 3 folders home,public, etc..
So where i have to keep my transformation file so that i can able to access it while selecting from **select transformation file**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a separate folder/directory *(e.g.: Transformations)* inside any of the already present directories *(say: Admin)*. Next **refresh** your repository/cache and you will be able to see the files. Link it from your CDE.

Now ideally when building a project, i used to have a separate folder with my project initials *say PROJECT*. Inside this folder, i used to create the rest of the sub-folders. This helps in separating the project codes.

Hope this helps :)

---

Edit:

The files in user console cannot be accessed from your local system post pentaho version 5. The only way to upload or download file is either to load it from User console or execute commands from command line. Check the below link. The files are internally stored in jackrabbit repository of pentaho bi server.

http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fadmin_guide%2Ftask_import_export_repository.html

Extra note: If you still want to access the files, there is REST API to handle most of the pentaho bi server capabilites. You may check this link also: http://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.2/0R0/070/010/0A0/0Q0#

Comment: My question is where and how can i create folder?
because i know only one way to create folder like inside CDE..
but how can i find it in my local system? 
if you can tell me the location in my machine, that is good enough.

Comment: @WorkingHard.. No you cannot find it in your locale. These files are stored inside internal repository of User console. The only way to upload or download file is either from User console or executing a command from the command line. I give the link above.